# See hidden property of Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects

I am trying to handle errors in node.js.

When I run `console.log(error)` I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
at solrClient.search.then.res (/.../schema.js:72:20)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
```

But if I try to run `Object.keys(error)` I get `[]` empty array. For different errors I do get `['message', 'code', 'type', 'errno']`.

When trying to access the property of the above written error then `error.message` still works.

**Is it possible despite those properties being hidden, to get their names?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.keys` returns only own enumerable properties. If it returns nothing, this means that `message` is either inherited from a prototype or is non-enumerable, the latter is the case for `TypeError` properties.

Non-enumerable properties can be listed with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(error)`.

Inherited properties can be retrieved by iterating over prototypes:

```
let proto = error;

while (proto) {
  console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto));
  proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The TypeError is not an array/map, is an exception instance well defined:

**if (e instanceof TypeError)**

Example:

```
catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof TypeError) {
      // Output expected TypeErrors.
      //Here try to get the information you need here
      logging.log(e);
    } else {
      // Output unexpected Errors.
      logging.log(e, false);
    }
```

Take a look:
https://airbrake.io/blog/nodejs-error-handling/node-typeerror

Answer (score 0):

May be it is not true but I think problem in next...

You are using solr-node-client library. This library depended on bluebird library.
Last library create own TypeError class like this code:

```
function subError(nameProperty, defaultMessage) {
    function SubError(message) {
        if (!(this instanceof SubError)) return new SubError(message);
        notEnumerableProp(this, "message",
            typeof message === "string" ? message : defaultMessage);
        notEnumerableProp(this, "name", nameProperty);
        if (Error.captureStackTrace) {
            Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
        } else {
            Error.call(this);
        }
    }
    inherits(SubError, Error);
    return SubError;
}
```

And this code set message and name attributes as not enumerable.