# Print all properties of an Error in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Normally an Error class has properties such as name, code, message, stack etc. Some special errors such as OpenSSL Error uses Error class but also have opensslErrorStack etc. How can I print all properties in an Error?

I tried:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
  for (let i in err) {
    console.log(i + ': ' + err[i]);
  }
});
```

Comment: Might be a duplicate but you can check the answers to my question, might bring you forward: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54323823/see-hidden-property-of-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To just print the error object with all its properties in Node.js you can use [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilinspectobject-options):

```js
const { inspect } = require('util');

process.on('uncaughtException', err => {
  console.log(inspect(err, { showHidden: true }));
});
```